# How I can delete a row form entity while using ManytoOne?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, entity, cascade

I have two Entities: Order and items.
Each order has many item.

```
public class Order extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="order_id", updatable = false)
    private String order_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(name="order_number", updatable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Column(name="date_created")
    private String dateCreated;

    @Column(name="expected_money_range")
    private Integer expectedMoneyRange;

    @Column(name="total_amount")
    private Double totalAmount;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = true)
    private Customer customer;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "order")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Item> item = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And

```
public class Item extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", updatable = false)
    private String Item_Id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String Description;

    @Column(name = "images")
    private byte[] Images;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = true)
    private Order order;
}
```

But when I want to delete an Order, nothing happens.

I am using orderRepository.deleteById(orderId).
I tried also to add orphan removal but nothing happens. Can anyone please help?

Log:
2021-12-08 14:51:18,575 [15957096]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS)
2021-12-08 14:51:18,589 [15957110]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/marwa/Documents/ESDT Projects/deliverytest
2021-12-08 14:51:18,894 [15957415]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 331 ms: 0 min 0sec
2021-12-08 14:51:18,909 [15957430]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened
2021-12-08 14:51:18,979 [15957500]   INFO - ij.execution.JavaExecutionUtil - Agent jars were copied to /Users/marwa/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/captureAgent
2021-12-08 14:51:19,520 [15958041]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2021-12-08 14:51:21,867 [15960388]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
2021-12-08 14:51:21,867 [15960388]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
2021-12-08 14:51:21,867 [15960388]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
2021-12-08 14:51:21,867 [15960388]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
2021-12-08 14:51:21,867 [15960388]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-12-08 14:52:36,515 [16035036]  DEBUG - BackendServerFileEditorManager - Opening host editor for /Users/marwa/Documents/ESDT Projects/deliverytest/src/main/java/com/esdt/deliverytest/Order/Service/OrderServiceImpl.java
2021-12-08 14:53:43,524 [16102045]  DEBUG - BackendServerFileEditorManager - Opening host editor for /Users/marwa/Documents/ESDT Projects/deliverytest/src/main/java/com/esdt/deliverytest/Order/Service/OrderServiceImpl.java

Comment: well in that case you need `OrphanRemoval` for sure
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",orphanRemoval=true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> item = new ArrayList<>();`

And could you tell more about your situation, is there any errors, can you post the log?
What do you mean by Nothing happens? Does the order get removed but the items stay or neither the order nad the items will be removed?

Comment: hi, no there are no error but Neither the order nor the items are deleted. I want when i delete the order, the items will be deleted too.

Comment: Does deleteById() work on other entities with an `id` having a String type?

Comment: I can imagine that the id has to be Long and not String but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: yes deleteById work on other entities with String id.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I couldn't find anything helpful. Please share it here too if you find the right answer to your qustion.

Comment: Hello, I didn't find the answer yet.

Comment: Inside postgres I can delete row. but when i delete from postman, the row is not deleted.

Comment: Can you post your debug log? I would like to see the log where the deleteById() is executed.

Comment: Hey, Sorry for late reply. There are no error. The response of delete API is 200 OK but nothing happens in the database.

Comment: Still, your debug log can be helpful. Just make a breakpoint and upload the debugging log here. To be honest, I can't think of anything, why it's not working, but maybe we can figure something out, when we see the log.

Comment: I added the log file in the post.

Comment: Is this the log from the part where you run repository.deleteById()? 
Because I can't see anything related to Hibernate/JPA, only the build and compile part of your project. To do that, set a breakpoint in the line where you run repository.deleteById(), and run your project in debug mode - while running the deleteById() line, send the console log from that part. 

Please forgive me if I just gave you the instructions you already know or just did - I wasn't sure, so I thought I'd write it down here.